# Passing data between two different components via services

Tags: angular

I tried to pass 'ele' which is an array contaning details about my recipe from `recipe-item.component.ts` to `recipe-detail.component.ts` and was successful in that and received it in the variable called `selectedrecipe` but then when I try to display the details in `recipe-detail.component.html` via `{{selectedrecipe.imagepath}}` and `{{selectedrecipe.name}}`
 .It throws the error and says ERROR

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'imagepath' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (RecipeDetailsComponent.html:3)

Here is the output of console.log(this.selectedrecipe) https://ibb.co/bvy1Gm0

**recipe-item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from 'src/app/shared/recipe.modal';
import { Recipeservice } from '../../recipe.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-recipe-item',
templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./recipe-item.component.css']
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() ele:Recipe
constructor(private reservice:Recipeservice) { }

ngOnInit() {

}
onrecipeclicked(){
this.reservice.recipeselected.emit(this.ele)
}
}
```

**recipe.service.ts**

```
import { Recipe } from '../shared/recipe.modal';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class Recipeservice{
recipeselected=new EventEmitter<Recipe>()
recipes:Recipe[]=[
    new Recipe('Big Fat Burger','What else you need to say 
?','https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702- 
sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg'),
    new Recipe('Tasty Schnitzel','A super tasty burger',' 
https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702- 
sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg')
 ]

 }
```

**recipe-details.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipeservice } from '../recipe.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-recipe-details',
templateUrl: './recipe-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./recipe-details.component.css']
})
export class RecipeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private reservice:Recipeservice) { }
selectedrecipe
ngOnInit() {
this.reservice.recipeselected.subscribe((recipe)=>{
this.selectedrecipe=recipe
console.log(this.selectedrecipe)
})
}

}
```

**recipe-details.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <img src="{{selectedrecipe.imagepath}}" alt=" . 
{{selectedrecipe.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max- 
height:300px">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
type="button">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a  style="cursor:pointer;">Shopping List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">

</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <!-- Ingredients -->
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"
    >
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this: `<span *ngIf="selectedrecipe"><img src="{{selectedrecipe.imagepath}}" alt=" . 
{{selectedrecipe.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max- 
height:300px"></span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the `selectedrecipe` being set asynchronously, you should use either a default value on your `@Input()` or use the save navigation operator `?.` inside your template:"

```
<img src="{{selectedrecipe?.imagepath}}" alt="{{selectedrecipe?.name}}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way by checking the variable itself in the `*ngIf` condition before going for any property:

```
<span *ngIf="selectedrecipe">
    <img src="{{selectedrecipe.imagepath}}" alt="{{selectedrecipe.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:300px">
</span>
```